# woocommerce Checkout page Select Type not working

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am Adding some Custom Fields to my checkout Form of woocommerce, text fiels are showing Exact Values on order summary page (for User/Cliecnt) and Same for Admin. But if i Use "Selcet" type, it is not showing the Actual Value

Here is the Code

```
 // Add a new checkout field
function kia_filter_checkout_fields($fields){
$fields['extra_fields'] = array(
        'some_field' => array(
            'type' => 'text',
            'required'      => true,
            'label' => __( 'Some field' )
            ),
        'another_field' => array(
            'type' => 'select',
            'options' => array( 'a' => __( 'apple' ), 'b' => __( 'bacon' ), 'c' => __( 'chocolate' ) ),
            'required'      => true,
            'label' => __( 'Another field' )
            )
        );

return $fields;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'kia_filter_checkout_fields' );

// display the extra field on the checkout form
function kia_extra_checkout_fields(){ 

$checkout = WC()->checkout(); ?>

<div class="extra-fields">
<h3><?php _e( 'Additional Fields' ); ?></h3>

<?php 
// because of this foreach, everything added to the array in the previous                   function will display automagically
foreach ( $checkout->checkout_fields['extra_fields'] as $key => $field ) : ?>

        <?php woocommerce_form_field( $key, $field, $checkout->get_value( $key ) ); ?>

    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

```
SAVE THE EXTRA DATA ON CHECKOUT
// save the extra field when checkout is processed
function kia_save_extra_checkout_fields( $order_id, $posted ){
// don't forget appropriate sanitization if you are using a different field   type
 if( isset( $posted['some_field'] ) ) {
    update_post_meta( $order_id, '_some_field', sanitize_text_field(   $posted['some_field'] ) );
}
if( isset( $posted['another_field'] ) && in_array( $posted['another_field'], array( 'a', 'b', 'c' ) ) ) {
    update_post_meta( $order_id, '_another_field', $posted['another_field'] );
}
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta',   'kia_save_extra_checkout_fields', 10, 2 );

DISPLAY THE EXTRA DATA TO USERS

// display the extra data on order recieved page and my-account order review
function kia_display_order_data( $order_id ){  ?>
<h2><?php _e( 'Additional Info' ); ?></h2>
<table class="shop_table shop_table_responsive additional_info">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th><?php _e( 'Some Field:' ); ?></th>
            <td><?php echo get_post_meta( $order_id, '_some_field', true );  ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th><?php _e( 'Another Field:' ); ?></th>
            <td><?php echo get_post_meta( $order_id, '_another_field', true  ); ?></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<?php }
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'kia_display_order_data', 20 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_view_order', 'kia_display_order_data', 20 );
```

So instead of "Apple"(in my case it is gender), it is showing "a" at Summary page after Checkout , here is the screenshot
[Screenshot for the reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtc40.png)

Here is the Tutorial Link : http://www.kathyisawesome.com/woocommerce-customize-checkout-fields/ and Woocommerce version is 2.5.5

Please Help,
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
 'options' => array( 
                    'a' => __( 'apple' ), 
                    'b' => __( 'bacon' ), 
                    'c' => __( 'chocolate' ) 
                    ),
```

with

```
'options' => array(
'' => _('Please Select An Option...', 'woocommerce'),
'a' => _('Apple', 'woocommerce' ),
'b' => _('Bacon', 'woocommerce' ),
'c' => _('Chocolate', 'woocommerce' )
),
```

or

```
'options' => array( 'a' => 'Apple',
                    'b'  => 'Bacon',
                    'c'  => 'Chocolate' ),
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks But nothing happened, same Output as before.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//* Add select field to the checkout page
add_action('woocommerce_before_order_notes', 'wps_add_select_checkout_field');
function wps_add_select_checkout_field( $checkout ) {

    echo '<h2>'.__('Next Day Delivery').'</h2>';

    woocommerce_form_field( 'daypart', array(
        'type'          => 'select',
        'class'         => array( 'wps-drop' ),
        'label'         => __( 'Delivery options' ),
        'options'       => array(
            'blank'     => __( 'Select a day part', 'wps' ),
            'morning'   => __( 'In the morning', 'wps' ),
            'afternoon' => __( 'In the afternoon', 'wps' ),
            'evening'   => __( 'In the evening', 'wps' )
        )
 ),

    $checkout->get_value( 'daypart' ));

}
```

From: https://www.wpstud.io/add-custom-select-field-woocommerce-checkout-page/